How to import types from openai in deno?
In official npm openai package description
https://www.npmjs.com/package/openai
i see

You can also import from jsr:
import OpenAI from 'jsr:@openai/openai';

but typing
deno add jsr:@openai/openai

I getting
error: jsr:@openai/openai was not found.

and in jsr link
https://jsr.io/@openai/openai
i see

This package has not published any versions yet.


Do anyone know why?
Is it common for other packages?
How to use openai in deno?

I using it by
import OpenAI from "npm:openai";

and it works but when I importing type
import { ChatCompletionCreateParamsStreaming } from "npm:openai";

I see typescript waring
Deno: Module "npm:openai" has no exported member ChatCompletionCreateParamsStreaming. Did you mean to use


There is still no package in jsr:@openai/openai so README.md of https://github.com/openai/openai-node contains a probably temporary bug.
But I found solution.
Instead of import
import { ChatCompletionCreateParamsStreaming } from 'npm:openai';

I just importing
import OpenAI from 'npm:openai';

and using required type by
const requestPayload: OpenAI.Chat.ChatCompletionCreateParams = {
    model,
    messages: [
        { role: 'system', content: system },
        { role: 'user', content: sourceText },
    ],
};

